# Flash On IE8 Problem

Tags: html, flash, object, internet-explorer-8, dreamweaver

Please help! I'm designing an HTML website and added an animated Flash image using the object tag. I was handcoding on Dreamweaver and before I saved it I got this message asking me if the code should be modified for compatibility with IE8.

So I just clicked on 'Yes' and a 'script' folder was generated.

The Flash image appears on Firefox 3.5 but comes up with the dreaded red 'x' on IE8.

Comment: code would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at google's [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)